# Select specific values from List

Tags: c#, list, linq

I want to select all values from prices from a list by a specific Name.
This is my code:

```
var singleNameWithOldestPrice =
    from p in PriceList
    group p by p.NAME into grp
    select grp.OrderBy(a => a.TIMESTAMP);
```

Now I get all the Names from `PriceList` with all the existing prices orderby Timestamp. But I only want specific Name with all the prices orderby Timestamp.

How can I do that?

Comment: What about filtering the name with `where` clause just before `group`?

Comment: [WHERE?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations#filtering)

Comment: Try adding a .where(p.Name == name).

Comment: Thanks guys! It works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Groupby` is superfluous, use `Where`

```
var mylist = PriceList.Where(x => x.Name == "your name")
                      .OrderBy(x => x.Timestamp)
                      .ToList();
```

[Enumerable.Where Method (IEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.